DiscriminationThreshold() for catboost
visualizer = DiscriminationThreshold(estimator, is_fitted=True, exclude="queue_rate", random_state=42)
visualizer.fit(X_val, y_val)
visualizer.show()

When I use the above code with estimators such as random forest, xgboost and lightgbm, it works perfectly.
However, when I try to use the same code for the catboost estimator, the following error appears:
YellowbrickTypeError: Cannot detect the model name for non estimator: '<class 'catboost.core.CatBoostClassifier'>'

I asked about this in the yellowbrick issues on github and they advised me to use the module they built within the library for estimators that are not scikit-learn estimators:
https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/contrib/wrapper.html
I tried, but unfortunately, I was unable to set the parameters needed to use the wrapper.
Could someone, please, help me use this wrapper, with the same objective as the code I mentioned at the beginning of this text, but in this case for the CatBoostClassifier?
Thank you in advance!
I have already tried both alternatives below and they did not work:
from yellowbrick.contrib.wrapper import classifier

cat_wrap = classifier(cat)

visualizer = DiscriminationThreshold(cat_wrap, is_fitted=True, random_state=42)
visualizer.fit(X_val, y_val)
visualizer.show()

TypeError: ContribEstimator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'learning_rate'

and
from yellowbrick.contrib.wrapper import wrap, CLASSIFIER

cat_wrap = wrap(cat, CLASSIFIER)

visualizer = DiscriminationThreshold(cat_wrap, is_fitted=True, random_state=42)
visualizer.fit(X_val, y_val)
visualizer.show()

TypeError: ContribEstimator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'learning_rate'

